# Python- plotting multiple graphs on same figure in frame in Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, plot, graph

I am building a GUI where values from some models will show graphs upon button click. As of now it works with one graph but when i try to plot the second graph, both of them plotted but merged. I want them to show separately inside one frame. For now, i am using tkinter canvas for plotting. Here is what i have done till now-

```
    f = Figure(figsize=(3,3), dpi=100)
    def graph1():

        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16])
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self.RightFrame)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=LEFT)
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=LEFT)
    def graph2():
        a = f.add_subplot(121)
        a.plot([6, 9, 12, 15], [20, 25, 30, 35])
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self.RightFrame)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=LEFT)
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=LEFT)

    Button(self.RightFrame,text='Show Graph1',command=graph1).pack(side=TOP)    
    Button(self.RightFrame,text='Show Graph2',command=graph2).pack(side=TOP)
```

code for the frame is below-

```
    self.RightFrame = Frame(Tab1)
    self.RightFrame.place(relx=0.165, rely=0.066, relheight=0.83, relwidth=0.842)
    self.RightFrame.configure(relief='groove')
    self.RightFrame.configure(borderwidth="2")
```

The graphs i am getting-
[image]

Instead of pack(), i tried to use grid and place but still nothing. I want to plot at least 4 graphs. What am i doing wrong/missing here? Thank you

P.S. i am using sample values for basic plotting for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i found an way to do plots. I am using separate figures for each graph. but cannot align the navigationtoolbar under each figures yet.

```
     def graph1():
        f = Figure(figsize=(3,3), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16])

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self.RightFrame)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().place(relx=0.010,rely=0.100)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self.RightFrame)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.place(relx=0.001,rely=0.100)
     def graph2():
        f2 = Figure(figsize=(3,3), dpi=100)
        a = f2.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot([6, 9, 12, 15], [20, 25, 30, 35])
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f2, self.RightFrame)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().place(relx=0.310,rely=0.100)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self.RightFrame)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.place(relx=0.310,rely=0.100)
```

The view-
[image]